# Create empty columns with mutate, column names from a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

There is a data frame df containing one column.

```
df <- data.frame(pseudonym = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

df
  pseudonym
1         a
2         b
3         c
4         d
```

Now I like to create empty columns with column names coming from a character vector (df2 and sn).

```
sn <- c("sn01", "sn02", "sn03")

sn
[1] "sn01" "sn02" "sn03"
```

df2 should be

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  pseudonym = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  sn01 = NA,
  sn02 = NA,
  sn03 = NA,
  sn04 = NA
)

df2
  pseudonym sn01 sn02 sn03 sn04
1         a   NA   NA   NA   NA
2         b   NA   NA   NA   NA
3         c   NA   NA   NA   NA
4         d   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I'm searching for a tidyverse statement somethink like this

```
df2 <- mutate___(df, ..., sn)
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: A non-tidyverse statement would be `df[,sn]<-NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not really in the spirit of the tidyverse, but you can do

```r
df %>% mutate(`[<-`(df, sn, value = NA))
#>   pseudonym sn01 sn02 sn03
#> 1         a   NA   NA   NA
#> 2         b   NA   NA   NA
#> 3         c   NA   NA   NA
#> 4         d   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: What does this   `[<-`  mean? Is it a function or an operator?

Comment: @poetspie in R, operators _are_ functions. `[<-` is the explicit name of the function that is actually called by the R parser when you do `df[sn] <- NA`

Comment: It is same as Mael suggested in the comments, but inside mutate.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks. Is there a documentation about [<- ?

Comment: @poetspie yes - type `?'[<-'` inyour console.

Comment: @AllanCameron When I use `df[, a] <- value` and the column index _a_ doesn't exist, it will be created.  I didn't know that, but now.